# regular expression for 10 digit mobile number with telephone numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I want to make a regular expression for *10 digit mobile numbers* with telephone numbers. Example are

```
 9088534816
+91 33 40653155
 033-2647-0969
```

I want make a *regular expression* that can match all three formats like

```
 xxxxxxxxxx
+xx xx xxxxxxxx
 xxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

formats. Can any one help me, please? I have tried with this

```
\+?\d[\d -]{8,12}\d
```

but it is taking also this number 12115351689385. That is my problem

Comment: any first attempts of your own?

Comment: yes that is mine
\+?\d[\d -]{8,12}\d

Comment: Design and test each pattern *separately*: `^[0-9]{10}$`, `^\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{8}$` etc. Then *combine* them: `^([0-9]{10})|(\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{8})|...|(...)$`

Comment: you can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41974491/edit) button below your post, to include further information. Just add the regular expression from you comment.

Comment: my expression also taking 12115351689385 this numbers that is a problem

Comment: it is not working

Comment: i wrote your expression like this

Comment: var exp = new Regex(@"^([0-9]{10})|(\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{8})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: but it is not working

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko gave you an answer for 1st two patterns. Last one would be ([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}\)

Comment: @JaneDoe "[0-9]" can be simplified to "\d". Also, in that context, there's no need to escape "-", and you should *not* be escaping "^". Then finally, the second group of numbers should be 3 digits long to be a valid phone number, not 4.

Comment: Why do you need RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, when you use only digits?

Comment: i wrote this full expressions like this

Comment: var exp = new Regex(@"^([0-9]{10})|(\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{8})|([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: actually i am fetching list of mobile numbers with telephone numbers from a string

Comment: @Abion47, I corrected my answer, removing ^, I first wrote the expression to work separately with beginning and end signs. About second group - I'm following santanu's pattern xxx-xxxx-xxxx which is 3, 4 and 4. 
As to my knowledge minus needs escaping because it is a special character.

Comment: When you design programm try do it as simple as possible. Simple code - less bugs, more maintainability... It is simple task, don't write pattern-that-cant-placed-on-one-monitor-line ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Design and test each pattern *separtely*:

```
  Format            Pattern
 ------------------------------------------------- 
  xxxxxxxxxx       ^[0-9]{10}$
 +xx xx xxxxxxxx   ^\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{8}$ 
  xxx-xxxx-xxxx    ^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$
 ....
```

then *combine* them into the final one:

```
 (pattern1)|(pattern2)|...|(patternN)
```

For the three patterns above the combined pattern is

```
 (^[0-9]{10}$)|(^\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$)|(^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$)
```

you can implement something like this:

```
 //TODO: you may want to load the patterns supported from resource, file, settings etc.
 private static string[] m_Patterns = new string[] {
   @"^[0-9]{10}$",
   @"^\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$",
   @"^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$",
 };

 private static string MakeCombinedPattern() {
   return string.Join("|", m_Patterns
     .Select(item => "(" + item + ")"));
 }
```

Tests:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "9088534816",
  "+91 33 40653155",
  "033-2647-0969",
  "123",
  "12115351689385",
};

var result = string
  .Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => 
     $"{test,18} {(Regex.IsMatch(test, MakeCombinedPattern()) ? "yes" : "no"),3}"));

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
        9088534816 yes
   +91 33 40653155 yes
     033-2647-0969 yes
               123  no
    12115351689385  no
```

Comment: it is not taking simple 10 digit mobile numbers like 9088534816

Comment: it is taking like +91 9632226066 working fine but 9088534816 is not taking

Comment: can it be so that you have a space in the string? It should work otherwise.

Comment: @santanu Bhatachraya: I've edited my answer (`^` and `$` should be within each `(...)`); I've extended test cases as well (you can easily add your own ones). As far as I can see from the outcome the test have been passed

Comment: and what if one more format? xxxx-xxxx xx for example? What is point in using RegEx if you have to add each format manually? Or misstype in input and number will be "xx--xx xxxx xx" then what? :) The number is correct, 10 digits, just a little mistake. @santanuBhatachraya maybe you should just create mask on input field?

Comment: i wrote like this
  var exp = new Regex(@"(^[0-9]{10}$)|(^\+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$)|(^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: @Sergio: As I've put in the comment "//TODO: you may want to load the patterns supported from resource, file, settings etc."

Comment: That what i was talking about... You need to find simple 10 digits, and you pattern is like persian carpet. Just remove ALL "-" and " ".

Comment: @Sergio: that's why it is the routine that should assemble the final pattern;  when developer has to provide simple readable chunks

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your input string first (to simplify RegEx pattern)

```
phones = phones.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-","");
```

And now just find numbers...

```
var m = Regex.Matches(a, @"\+?[0-9]{10}");
```

Answer (score 1):

For Iran Mobile Number syntax is `^[0][9]\d{9}$`

Answer (score 0):

The first and third format (and indeed most of the more common US phone number formats) can be combined into a single Regex pattern:

```
^[(]?\d{3}[)]?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$
```

The second format is more tricky, since it is an international phone number. Different countries have different number formats, so it's less straightforward to parse. If you wish to add support for a specific country like in your example, you can write a pattern for it as well. Your specific example would be:

```
^\+\d{2} \d{2} \d{8}$
```

*(I can't optimize it for multiple conventions like I did the first pattern because I'm not familiar with that phone number format. I don't know if it allows for dashes or if the spaces or optional or any other cultural variances.)*

After you have all the patterns you want, you can combine them like how Dmitry's answer suggests with `String.Join`, then use the result as the pattern for a `Regex.Match / Regex.Matches` call.

Answer (score 0):

**Regular expression for valid PhoneNumber**

```cs
 public static bool IsPhoneNumberValid(this string phone)
  {
     bool isValid = false;
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phone))
         {
       isValid = Regex.IsMatch(phone, @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
         }
       
     return isValid;
        
    }
```